# best linux tool to transfer thousand of files between two servers

Tags: linux, rsync, webserver, scp, migration

If you think it's a duplicate...well i didnt find a satisfying answer yet :/

I have to migrate a folder from a server to another. Personally I would use rsync but the question is...this folder contains both big files (> 5gb) and many small files ( over 1k <30kb files).

I would like to avoid the bottleneck caused by the many small files transfer.

Is rsync the right tool to do this or there are better solutions?

SCP is even slower, just in case someone suggest it.

Comment: You are looking for an opinion-based answer, which you won't get on this site. Try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead, but you need to be clear on what you mean by _best_: fastest, most secure, lowest overhead, easiest to use, or other criteria? For myself, if the servers are geographically close, I'd use an external disc for such a large transfer.

Comment: thanks for the comment.
I'm not asking for an opinion-based answer, i should specify that i'm looking for the fastest solution. Unluckily physical movements can't be used due to many factors (mainly burocratics). I used to clone the machine directly but in this case would be a waste of time and space.

Comment: @WyattGillette You are still looking for a software recommendation, and here at Superuser, questions that seem software recommendations (which you confirmed twice was the case) is not within scope.

Comment: You're asking for a product recommendation (**linux tool**), and clearly opinion-based (**best** linux tool), which is clearly indicated as being off-topic in the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: Some of these commenters need to read the guidelines themselves instead of making up their own. According to the guidelines this is on topic and I'm grateful that it's been asked and answered. I'm now migrating data between 2 NAS devices and I cannot take the source machine offline. This solution is perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one off transfer, rsync is NOT the tool for the job.

The way I would do it would be to tar the files (and optionally compress, depending on the characteristics of the servers and connection between them), then pipe that via SSH onto the new server and decompress it.   This can be done in 1 command.  You will need to vary it depending on the specifics, but it would look something like:

```
tar -cz /startdir | pv | ssh user@ip "cd /destpath; tar -xf"
```

This will compress the files into a single stream so there is not a lot of back-and-forth for each file giving you maximum speed.  It also does the compress, shipping and decompression in a single step, so it will minimize the overall time taken.

To break down how it works:

tar compresses/decompresses the files into a stream on stdout (because a filename is not given). the -c means create, and z means compress.  You can leave out the z if compression is not desired.

The pv bit is not needed, but provides feedback that the data is being transferred, and the rate of transfer of the compressed data.
The ssh command of-course creates the connection to the remote side, and feeds the output of the previous commands to it.  It then jumps to the appropriate directory and decompresses it.

Comment: I like that! This does not wait until the tar command finishes, but streams it continuously over to the remote host. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: that's excellent and it's exactly what i needed, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use `find ... -size` to `tar` the files under a given size into a single big one, then use `rsync .... --min-size` to transfer only files above a given size.